# CloudWatch Container Insights query to catch Kubernetes exponential backoff

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following CloudWatch query that triggers on restarts of pods with 5 restarts over 5 mins:

```
  evaluation_periods  = 1
  datapoints_to_alarm = 1
  threshold           = 5
  actions_enabled     = true

  metric_query = [{
    id          = "id1"
    label       = "ContainerRestarts"
    return_data = true
    expression  = "SELECT SUM(pod_number_of_container_restarts) FROM SCHEMA(ContainerInsights, ClusterName, FullPodName, Namespace, PodName) WHERE ClusterName = 'cluster-123' AND Namespace = 'namespace-123'"
    period      = 300
  }]
```

However, in the case of Kubernetes exponential backoff, this would not catch that. Is there a way to modify this expression to catch pods that are restarting with intervals longer and longer each time?